# Creating a wavelet in Matlab

Tags: matlab, wavelet

I have some reflectivity data which I am going to convolute with a Ricker/mexican hat wavelet to get a seismic trace. My problem is due to creating the wavelet. I would like the wavelet to have a dominant frequency of about 70Hz and the time step to be 0.19 ms, which is the same time step as in my reflectivity data. I have tried to use the function mexihat in MatLab and tuned the lb, ub and n parameters to solve my problem, but I can´t figure it out. Is there an easier way to solve my problem? Does anyone know a formula for the Ricker wavelet where the dominant frequency occurs?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Dsp.stackexchange.com might have been a better place for this question

Answer (score 2):

From [Large Data in MATLAB: A Seismic Data Processing Case Study](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/30585-large-data-in-matlab-a-seismic-data-processing-case-study/content/migration/ricker.m) :

```
% N : number of points you want to plot
[rw,t] = ricker(70,N,0.019);
plot(t,rw), xlabel('Time'), ylabel('Amplitude')
```

Comment: Do you also have the function ricker? That is not a function preexisting in MatLab...

Comment: the link in my answer points toward the source code of the function : just copy paste it into a new ricker.m file and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

```
% using the equation below
% https://wiki.seg.org/wiki/Dictionary:Ricker_wavelet
ric = @(t,fm)(1-2*pi()^2*fm^2*t.^2)*exp(-1*pi()^2*fm^2*t.^2); % Ricker equation
t = 0:001:2;
plot(ric(t,20));
hold on;
plot(ric(t,5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Beware, I tried the function lucasg linked to and found a typo in the formula calculating the wavelet:

`s = (1-tau.*tau*f^2*pi^2).*exp(-tau.^2*pi^2*f^2);` 
should be replaced by: 
`s = (1-2*tau.*tau*f^2*pi^2).*exp(-tau.^2*pi^2*f^2);`

Otherwise, you will get a mutant ricker with small feet